# The limitation of $n \cos n \pi$

Tags: calculus

How to determine the sequence ${[n\cos n \pi]}$converges or diverges? I get stucked at $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n \cos n\pi)$$

Comment: Did you maybe try to calculate $n\cos n\pi$ for any particular value of $n$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\cos n\pi=\begin{cases}-1,&n\;\text{is odd}\\{}\\\;\;\,1,&n\;\text{is even}\end{cases}\;\;\implies n\cos n\pi=\begin{cases}-n,&n\;\text{is odd}\\{}\\\;\;\,n,&n\;\text{is even}\end{cases}$$